# dialogflow trigger event from webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have an intent I1 with action x and an intent I2 which calls a webhook.

Is there a way to trigger x from the I2 webhook response, in order to "redirect" the user to I1 after the webhook has given its answer?

Is there a way to do so from the dialogflow console?

Edit:
added diagram for further clarification.
What is the correct way to handle the "no" followup part?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Intents represent a user's input (typically what they say), not what you are "doing".

Although you can redirect from a webhook (such as your I2 handler) to an event (which might be picked up by I1), you can't do it "after" the webhook replies. This would replace the result from the webhook. (And, while possible, it is usually not the best approach to a problem.)

You also cannot do this from the Dialogflow configuration. It must be done through a webhook.

**Update** based on your diagram.

Your diagram illustrates why we encourage people to think about *conversations* and what the user *says* rather than "what do we do". Conversation diagrams aren't quite the same as flow charts. Let me restructure that as a few scripts (which we will annotate later).

Script 1:

```
User:  Talk to number or letter
Agent: Welcome! Would you like to hear a number or letter? 
User:  How about a number
Agent: 1 is the loneliest number. Would you like another?
User:  Yes
Agent: 2 is the only even prime. Care for another?
User:  No
Agent: Ok, would you like to hear a number or letter?
```

Script 2:

```
User:  Talk to number or letter
Agent: Welcome! Would you like to hear a number or a letter?
User:  Number, please
Agent: 42 is the answer Another one, so to speak?
User:  sure
Agent: 21 is blackjack. Care for another?
User:  nope
Agent: Ok, care for a letter or a number?
```

Script 3:

```
User:  Talk to number or letter
Agent: Howdy! Would you like a letter or a number?
User:  Let's go for a number
Agent: A googol is 10 to the 100th power. Ready for another?
User:  How about a letter this time
Agent: The letter "A" is one of only two letters that are also words. Want another?
```

There are a few points to learn from this:

- People respond in many different ways when asked a question. Intents use many sample phrases, plus some ML algorithms, to match what the user says to how they can reply.
- In real conversations, users can take the conversation in any direction. So although we've asked a yes or no question, they may try to take the conversation in a whole different direction instead.
- How we reply depends on two things:

  1. What state we were in
  2. What the user says
- A consequence of point (1) above is that we should keep track of the user's state to determine what we say, so the new state becomes part of the reply, even if the user doesn't see that.

With that, let's add a little more information to see what Intent would get matched and then what our webhook would do - both in terms of state set and the reply sent.

Script 1:

```
User:  Talk to number or letter
Match: intent.welcome
Logic: Set replyState to "prompt"
       Pick a response for the current replyState ("prompt")
       and the intent that was matched ("intent.welcome")
Agent: Welcome! Would you like to hear a number or letter? 

User:  How about a number
Match: intent.number
Logic: Set replyState to "number"
       Pick a response for the current replyState ("number")
Agent: 1 is the loneliest number. Would you like another?

User:  Yes
Match: intent.yes
Logic: Pick a response for the current replyState ("number")
Agent: 2 is the only even prime. Care for another?

User:  No
Match: intent.no
Logic: Set replyState to "prompt"
       Pick a response for the current replyState ("prompt")
       and the intent that was matched (not "intent.welcome")
Agent: Ok, would you like to hear a number or letter?
```

With this, we can see that our replies are based on a combination of the current state and the user's intent. (Our state could be more complex, to keep track of what the user has heard, how many times they've visited, etc. This is very simplified.)

We also see that "yes" doesn't change the state. It doesn't need to.

If we look at script 2, we'll see it plays out identically:

```
User:  Talk to number or letter
Match: intent.welcome
Logic: Set replyState to "prompt"
       Pick a response for the current replyState ("prompt")
       and the intent that was matched ("intent.welcome")
Agent: Welcome! Would you like to hear a number or a letter?

User:  Number, please
Match: intent.number
Logic: Set replyState to "number"
       Pick a response for the current replyState ("number")
Agent: 42 is the answer Another one, so to speak?

User:  sure
Match: intent.yes
Logic: Pick a response for the current replyState ("number")
Agent: 21 is blackjack. Care for another?

User:  nope
Match: intent.no
Logic: Set replyState to "prompt"
       Pick a response for the current replyState ("prompt")
       and the intent that was matched (not "intent.welcome")
Agent: Ok, care for a letter or a number?
```

In fact, if you look at the "Match" and "Logic" parts, they are identical conversations as far as the program is concerned. The only difference is the exact words the user used and the exact phrases we replied with. They are, fundamentally, the exact same conversation.

How does this play out in script 3?

```
User:  Talk to number or letter
Match: intent.welcome
Logic: Set replyState to "prompt"
       Pick a response for the current replyState ("prompt")
       and the intent that was matched ("intent.welcome")
Agent: Howdy! Would you like a letter or a number?

User:  Let's go for a number
Match: intent.number
Logic: Set replyState to "number"
       Pick a response for the current replyState ("number")
Agent: A googol is 10 to the 100th power. Ready for another?

User:  How about a letter this time
Match: intent.letter
Logic: Set replyState to "letter"
       Pick a response for the current replyState ("letter")
Agent: The letter "A" is one of only two letters that are also words. Want another?
```

Here, the user has suddenly requested we jump to an entirely different state. But that isn't a problem - Dialogflow just saw this the same as if they requested that state from the prompting question and the handler for that reacts the same way.

So instead of having to build in many followup intents, we aim to capture what the user is saying, and then use our webhook to change the state based on that.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification; i am probably approaching this from the wrong angle then: if an agent does 2-3 things after an initial selection(I1) like "tell me a joke" (I2), "tell me a number"(I3), "tell me a colour"(I4), and each one ends with "another one please" (Ix)/ "no thank you"(Iy), what is the correct approach to redirect the user from Iy to I1 ?

Comment: Can you update your question to give a few illustrations of this, rather than try to put it into the comments?

Comment: That diagram was a GREAT illustration and made it very clear how you were thinking and what you were doing. However, it is an illustration of why "logic flow" or "code flow" isn't the best way to design a conversation. I've given a description of how to approach this by looking at the "conversation flow". With your permission, I'd like to adapt your question, and your diagram, and my answer into a longer post on Medium.

Comment: of course! if it could be helpful to someone else, I'm totally for it.Please, share the link afterwards i'd like to read the full post when available

Comment: Absolutely. Wanted to confirm - does this clear things up for you and give you a good approach to the problem?

Comment: I believe i got it, i think that this should be approached more like a Mealy machine than a flowchart. Thank you for your support, i found a bit hard to follow the documentation but your examples helped me a lot even on other doubts i had. Edit after i read your profile: i don't know how to contact someone to fix the docs: "expectUserResponse" is sometimes referred as "expectedUserResponse"

Comment: Here's the Medium post: https://medium.com/@afirstenberg/thinking-for-voice-design-conversations-not-logic-7c60869451f1

Comment: Great answer, except as someone finding this question having already arrived at the same spot, an example webhook response would make it perfect.

Comment: I've had some delays writing the third part of the Medium posts, which will cover the webhook portion. {: Stay tuned.